# Group data by columns and row values

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe `df`:

```
df =

REGION   GROUP_1   GROUP_2   GROUP_3
Reg1     AAA       BBB       AAA
Reg2     BBB       AAA       CCC
Reg1     BBB       CCC       CCC
```

I need to count the number of unique occurences of the values of `GROUP_1`, `GROUP_2` and `GROUP_3` grouped per `REGION` (the quantity of `GROUP_` columns is 50 in my real dataset).

For the above example, the result should be the following:

```
result = 

REGION    COUNT_AAA   COUNT_BBB   COUNT_CCC
Reg1      1           2           1
Reg2      1           1           1
```

This is my code:

```
df = (pd.melt(df, id_vars=['REGION'], value_name='GROUP')
 .drop('variable', axis=1).drop_duplicates()
 .groupby(['REGION', 'GROUP']).agg({'GROUP' : 'count'})
 .reset_index())
```

The problem is that it takes too much time for 1Gb of data. I cannot even check the result on the whole dataset because of very long calculation time. In my opinion, there is something wrong in the code or it can be simplified.

Comment: I don't really understand the logic that get you the result...Why in result for Reg1 COUNT_BBB is 2 while COUNT_AAA and COUNT_CCC are 1? Shouldn't be COUNTS_XXX in this case equal to 2?
The result for Reg2 is clear, since you have only one row and there three "types" appear each only once.

Comment: for Reg1 COUNT_BBB is 2 because BBB appears 1 time in GROUP_2 and 1 time in GROUP_1 in the 1st and 3rd rows accordingly (so, totally 2 unique (per row) occurences. In Reg1 COUNT_AAA is equal to 1, because is appears twice in the 1st row, but I count it only once, because I'm interested in unique occurences per row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `set_index`
- `value_counts`
- `notnull` converts 1s and 2s to `True` and `np.nan` to False
- `groupby` + `sum`

---

```
df.set_index('REGION').apply(
    pd.value_counts, 1).notnull().groupby(level=0).sum().astype(int)

        AAA  BBB  CCC
REGION               
Reg1      1    2    1
Reg2      1    1    1
```

---

***Even Faster***

```
val = df.filter(like='GROUP').values
reg = df.REGION.values.repeat(val.shape[1])
idx = df.index.values.repeat(val.shape[1])
grp = val.ravel()

pd.Series({(i, r, g): 1 for i, r, g in zip(idx, reg, grp)}).groupby(level=[1, 2]).sum().unstack()
```

***Faster Still***

```
from collections import Counter

val = df.filter(like='GROUP').values
reg = df.REGION.values.repeat(val.shape[1])
idx = df.index.values.repeat(val.shape[1])
grp = val.ravel()

pd.Series(Counter([(r, g) for _, r, g in pd.unique([(i, r, g) for i, r, g in zip(idx, reg, grp)]).tolist()])).unstack()
```

Comment: Perfect. I would just appreciate a tiny little bit of explanation accompanied to this oneliner. It is easier for beginners to break it down.

Comment: Why AAA and CCC for Reg1 is equal to 2? It should be 1. AAA appears twice in the first row, so I want to calculate it only once, since I am interested in unique (per row) occurences of group values.

Comment: Indeed this solution is very fast.

Answer (score 4):

You could start off with dropping duplicated values present among the `GROUP_X` columns. Then with the help of `lreshape`, consolidate these into a single `GROUP` column.

Perform `groupby` by making *REGION* as the grouped key and compute `value_counts` to get respective unique counts present in the *GROUP* column.

Finally, `unstack` to make the multi-index series to a dataframe and add an optional prefix to the column headers obtained.

***slow approach:***

```
(pd.lreshape(df.apply(lambda x: x.drop_duplicates(), 1), 
             {"GROUP": df.filter(like='GROUP').columns})
   .groupby('REGION')['GROUP'].value_counts().unstack().add_prefix('COUNT_'))
```

[image]

To obtain a flat `DF`:

```
(pd.lreshape(df.apply(lambda x: x.drop_duplicates(), 1), 
 {"GROUP": df.filter(like='GROUP').columns}).groupby('REGION')['GROUP'].value_counts()
 .unstack().add_prefix('COUNT_').rename_axis(None, 1).reset_index())
```

[image]

---

***slightly fast approach:***

With the help of `MultiIndex.from_arrays`, we could compute unique rows too.

```
midx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(df.filter(like='GROUP').values, names=df.REGION.values)
d = pd.DataFrame(midx.levels, midx.names)
d.stack().groupby(level=0).value_counts().unstack().rename_axis('REGION')
```

---

***faster approach:***

A Faster way would be to create the unique row values using `pd.unique`(faster than `np.unique` as it does not perform sort operation after finding the unique elements) while iterating through the array corresponding to `GROUP_X` column. This takes the major chunk of the time. Then, `stack`, `groupby`, `value_counts` and finally `unstack` it back.

```
d = pd.DataFrame([pd.unique(i) for i in df.filter(like='GROUP').values], df.REGION)
d.stack().groupby(level=0).value_counts(sort=False).unstack()
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to somehow speedup this code? It gives a correct result, but runs too long time on 1 Gb (indeed not so much data).

Comment: I know it isn't all that very efficient. I'll work on optimizing it.

Comment: @NickilMaveli I've updated my post.  See if you like it.

Comment: Your last 2 approaches are just too good. I'm always afraid of using loops especially when the size of the data tends to be huge. But this proved to be incredibly fast. Seeing this, I've also added a loop solution and a not so fast variant using multi-indexing which does the same thing.